# Highcharts tooltip functionality lost from version 2.2.1 to version 3.0.1

Tags: model-view-controller, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm displaying multiple charts on the screen, in a .NET MVC application, using Highcharts 3.0.1. Problem that I have is that the tool tips are not destroyed when moving from one chart to another one (or when I'm not hovering over the area with the chart data). So I ended up in having 3 tooltips displayed over the three charts that I'm displaying on the screen, even if my cursor is on another area of the screen. And also related to this, there is a java script error occurring when I exit the chart area, that says:

```
Unhandled exception at line 6090, column 2 in http://localhost:50204/Scripts/jquery-2.0.1.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected
```

- verified in IE 8, 9 and Mozilla Firefox as well.
  This is the code that is on the js file, at that line:

  // return a css property mapped to a potentially vendor prefixed property

  function vendorPropName( style, name ) {

  ```
  // shortcut for names that are not vendor prefixed
  if ( name in style ) {
      return name;
  }
  ```

  It seems that tries to use the IN operand on a string - style parameter contains the following, when the error occurs:

cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;

Error does not appear when I turn off the tooltip, so that's why I presumed is related to the tooltip.

I did also a regression test, and moved back on Highcharts version 2.2.1. On this version, the tooltips are behaving normally, tooltip is destroyed once we are exiting the chart data area. But unfortunately I can't use this version because of other functionality  that involves 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Set `hideDelay` to 0: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.hideDelay

Regarding error, recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: Sorry, setting HideDelay to zero did not work, I have the same behaviour.

Comment: Regarding jsFiddle, since the development is done in C# .NET and chart properties are all defined in C#, I'm afraid the problem is how this charts are translated in the final product (HTML/JS, etc). And even if trying to reproduce the bug, there is no explicit option to choose Highcharts 3.0.1 with JQUERY 2.0.1.

Comment: Maybe you are using some wrappers which doesn't support that option? http://jsfiddle.net/AnT5H/1/ - timeout is equal to 0, of course now there is animation fadeOut(), but tooltip won't stay long.

Comment: The only difference is that I have a .NET MVC project, no other wrappers. But strange thing is after referencing directly the scripts from Highcharts website, error is gone in Firefox and functionality is back, while in IE I receive now another error saying 'Highcharts' is undefined

Comment: Update Highcharts to the latest version (3.0.2) instead of 3.0.1. Without live example, I can not help so much..

Comment: It's kind of an example - took the column basic example, and move it to jQuery 2.0.2 - here's the link (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.0.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/), and nothing is displayed in IE, but the errors: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
 
jquery-2.0.2.js, line 1378 character 2
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
_display, line 21 character 1
On the other hand, on Mozilla Firefox, this works fine.

Comment: jsFiddle has issue with displaying in old IE, try fullscreen version: http://jsfiddle.net/e2ak2/show/ Btw, jQuery 2+ doesn't support old IE anymore.

Comment: But IE version is 9,  browser mode was IE9 and document mode was IE9 standards.

Comment: Just tested with IE v 9.0.8112.16421 and with `/show/` in URL works perfectly fine.

Comment: Downgraded to jQuery 1.5.1 and Highcharts 2.2.1 and works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to be version-specific. I fixed an identical error in my system by downloading the latest version of highcharts JS, replacing the one installed by NuGet.